# Dynamic Query with output parameter

Tags: sql-server

Can any one of you help me to convert this query into dynamic query

```
DECLARE @Measure_Code nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Transaction_Date datetime
DECLARE @Spec_Code nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Error_Code nvarchar(500)
DECLARE @Operation_Status bit
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(1000)

SET @Measure_Code = 'CFL_WATTS'
SET @Transaction_Date = 02/16/2010

PRINT @Transaction_Date

SET @Spec_Code = 'CFL_Watts = 45'
SET @Error_Code = NULL 
SET @Operation_Status = NULL

SET @Query = 'USP_TRM_MEASURE_EVALUATE ' + '@Measure_Code'+','+'@Transaction_Date'+','+'@Spec_Code'+','+
                '@Error_Code output'+','+'@OPERATION_STATUSoutput'

PRINT @Query

EXEC(@Query)
```

I want the output as

```
@QUERY = USP_TRM_MEASURE_EVALUATE @MeasureCode,@Transaction_Date, @Spec_Code, @Error_Code output, @Operation_Status output
```

Comment: why do you want to build that to a string and call exec? why not simply call it directly

Comment: While calling it directly it is showing some errors like
you have to declare the value for @Measure_Code

Comment: you should include 'EXECUTE ' at the start of the @Qury string, and also you need a space near the end here: '@OPERATION_STATUS output'

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a string into the Exec() function and expect that local variables inside that string will be treated as variables from your calling scope, either for passing into the proc or returning from the proc.

Just call the proc directly:

```
exec USP_TRM_MEASURE_EVALUATE @MeasureCode,@Transaction_Date, 
@Spec_Code, @Error_Code output, @Operation_Status output
```